# Concurrent ruby conflict error when running Jekyll commands

Tags: ruby, jekyll, rvm

I wanted to create a new Jekyll website so I ran `jekyll new website` but I received the following error:

```
Matejs-MacBook-Pro:~ matejlatin$ jekyll new website
/Users/matejlatin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/specification.rb:2290:in `raise_if_conflicts': Unable to activate concurrent-ruby-ext-1.1.3, because concurrent-ruby-1.1.4 conflicts with concurrent-ruby (= 1.1.3) (Gem::ConflictError)
    from /Users/matejlatin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1410:in `activate'
    from /Users/matejlatin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems.rb:220:in `rescue in try_activate'
    from /Users/matejlatin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems.rb:213:in `try_activate'
    from /Users/matejlatin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:126:in `rescue in require'
    from /Users/matejlatin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:40:in `require'
    from /Users/matejlatin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.4/lib/concurrent/utility/native_extension_loader.rb:62:in `try_load_c_extension'
    from /Users/matejlatin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.4/lib/concurrent/utility/native_extension_loader.rb:30:in `block in load_native_extensions'
    from /Users/matejlatin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.4/lib/concurrent/utility/native_extension_loader.rb:30:in `each'
    from /Users/matejlatin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.4/lib/concurrent/utility/native_extension_loader.rb:30:in `load_native_extensions'
    from /Users/matejlatin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.4/lib/concurrent/synchronization.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/matejlatin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:68:in `require'
    from /Users/matejlatin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:68:in `require'
    from /Users/matejlatin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.4/lib/concurrent/map.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/matejlatin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:120:in `require'
    from /Users/matejlatin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:120:in `require'
    from /Users/matejlatin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/i18n-0.9.5/lib/i18n.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/matejlatin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:120:in `require'
    from /Users/matejlatin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:120:in `require'
    from /Users/matejlatin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/jekyll-3.8.5/lib/jekyll.rb:38:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/matejlatin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:68:in `require'
    from /Users/matejlatin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:68:in `require'
    from /Users/matejlatin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/jekyll-3.8.5/exe/jekyll:8:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/matejlatin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/bin/jekyll:23:in `load'
    from /Users/matejlatin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/bin/jekyll:23:in `<main>'
    from /Users/matejlatin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
    from /Users/matejlatin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

I have no idea what that means and don't know where to even look at how to fix this. I'm on macOS Mojave 10.14.2

Comment: What is the output of running `gem list | grep concurrent`?

Comment: concurrent-ruby (1.1.4, 1.1.3, 1.0.5)
concurrent-ruby-ext (1.1.3, 1.0.5)

Comment: Try running `bundle update`, does it complete successfully?

Comment: I found out what was causing the problem. I was trying to run `jekyll new . --force` to try and create a new Jekyll website in the current folder. If I tried running the normal `jekyll new website` command after I would get the same error. I ran `gem cleanup` which removed the i18n-0.9.5 gem which makes the regular `jekyll new website` work again. Strange